# SQL - Select resources accessible by an user directly or via his group

Tags: sql, select, inner-join

I'm trying to list all the resources a user has access to. He can have a direct access (user permission) or being in a group which has access to the resource (group permission).

My tables would be:

- group: id, name
- user: id, name
- resource: id, name
- rel_resource_user: resource, user
- rel_group_resource: group, resource
- rel_group_user: group, user

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT resource.id 
FROM resource 
LEFT OUTER JOIN rel_group_resource ON resource.id = rel_group_resource.resource 
INNER JOIN `group` ON rel_group_resource.`group` = `group`.id 
INNER JOIN rel_group_user ON rel_group_user.`group` = `group`.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN rel_resource_user ON rel_resource_user.resource = resource.id 
WHERE rel_resource_user.user = 1 OR rel_group_user.user = 1
```

But I receive only the resources access via the group and not by the user directly. If I cut the query in two query, one for the resources accessed by groups and one by users directly, it works. But I'm not able to get all the resources in one query.

Thank you for you help !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use two `where resource.id in` like this:

```
select resource.id 
from resource
where resource.id in (select rel_resource_user.resource
                      from rel_resource_user
                      where rel_resource_user.user = 1) or
      resource.id in (select rel_group_resource.resource
                      from rel_group_resource
                        inner join rel_group_user
                          on rel_group_resource.group = rel_group_user.group
                      where rel_group_user.user = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If they have the same number of output fields and the same type you can use `UNION` or `UNION ALL`, the only difference is UNION gets rid of duplicates.

```
SELECT
   ResourceID
FROM 
   FIRSTTABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT ResourcedID
FROM
   SecondTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT r.id 
FROM resource AS r
WHERE EXISTS 
      ( SELECT *
        FROM rel_resource_user AS ru
        WHERE ru.resource = r.id
          AND ru.user = 1
      )
   OR EXISTS 
      ( SELECT *
        FROM rel_group_user AS gu
          JOIN `group` AS g
            ON g.id = gu.`group`
          JOIN rel_group_resource AS gr
            ON gr.`group` = g.id
        WHERE gr.resource = r.id
          AND gu.user = 1
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
select Resource_id  from
(
    select rel_resource_user.resource as Resource_id,user.id as user_id FROM user inner join rel_resource_user on rel_resource_user.user=user.id
UNION
     SELECT rel_group_resource..resource as Resource_id,rel_group_user.user as user_id FROM group inner join rel_group_resource on group.id= rel_group_resource.group INNER JOIN rel_group_user.group= group.id
)
```